# Feedly cannot download images from memebase rss

Tags: feedly

I wonder if anyone is experiencing this issue:

I have a few rss feeds from memebase in my feedly account.

Feedly gives the option to download (using a long press over the image) any image in the simplified article. However, for some reason, when I try to download an image from the memebase feeds I get the error:

```
"Error reading image (OPEN FAILED ENOENT (No such file))"
```

Anyone has any idea on why this is happening?